How can I get the first document from a firebase querySnapshot
I'm doing:
const querySnapshot = await db
      .collectionGroup('documents')
      .where('id', '==', id)
      .get();

And expecting a single document as a result. What's the easiest way to get it?

If you expect a single result, I'd recommend also adding a limit(1) clause to the query to ensure you're never reading more docs than one.

Turns out the actual document references are in querySnapshot.docs and querySnapshot.empty indicates whether or not there are any results so:
if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
  const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
...

Will give you the data from the first (and in this case presumably only) document in the results.
